# assign static IP to secondary wifi controller Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, static-ip

I have a secondary Wifi connection on a Raspberry Pi3.  The device drivers for this secondary adapter are loading fine.  The first adapter is the onboard adapter that connects to my home network and it works fine.  It is wlan0

I have set my /etc/network/interfaces file as such:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlx74da380d4bf5
iface wlx74da380d4bf5 inet static
address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I have updated the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file to:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

However at reboot, the Wifi Adapter is NOT assigned the static IP address.  I have two other services I am trying to start that do not work properly due to the Wifi adapter not having a static ip.  they are: hostapd and isc-dhcp-server.

If I manually run the commands...:

```
sudo ifconfig wlx74da380d4bf5 192.168.42.1
sudo service hostapd start 
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

...everything works properly.  Can someone spot what I am doing wrong to assign that wifi adapter a static IP of 192.168.42.1 at startup (automatically)?

TIA